# Core Plot - Very Low Frame Rate with Bar Plot on iPhone 5

Tags: ios, core-animation, core-plot

I have 390 points on my plot. The Frame rate is < 20 fps during pinch-zoom with both the scatter and bar plot. However if I only have a scatter plot on screen, i get ~50fps. When i used instruments, the main bottleneck seems to the  -[CPTBarPlot renderAsVectorInContext:] which has a run time of more than 50% where as scatter plot is <20%. Even when i plotted only the bar plot on screen, I cldn't get more than 20fps (but i still need to test it) . Is this the std performance of a bar plot? How can i improve this? I have already set the cache precision to be double.

I'll appreciate if someone can help me here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the barCornerRadius and barBaseCornerRadius have the default value of zero. Set the barWidth to zero. Set barWidthsAreInViewCoordinates to YES to speed up coordinate conversions. Set the fill to nil.

Comment: So did this effectively disable the bar plot from even showing? Width to zero and no fill?

Comment: No it did not. My linewidth for those bar plots was >0. So it still drew the bars